# How to create default radio button website

Tags: python, odoo

How to create default radio button website, I want to set default in radio button on morning in my website.

```
<template id="fal_shift_opt" inherit_id="website_sale.payment" customize_show="True" name="Shift Option">
      <xpath expr="//div[@id='delivery_carrier']" position="before">

              <div class="row" id="shift_option">
                <div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-8">
                  <h4>Choose your shift delivery</h4>
                      <ul class="list-unstyled">
                          <li>
                              <label>
                                  <input value="morning" type="radio" name="shift2"
                                    t-att-checked="order.shift2 == 'morning' and 'checked' or False"
                                    />
                                  <span>Morning</span>
                              </label>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                              <label>
                                  <input value="afternoon"  type="radio" name="shift2"
                                    t-att-checked="order.shift2 == 'afternoon' and 'checked' or False"
                                      />
                                  <span>Afternoon</span>
                              </label>
                          </li>
                      </ul>
                  </div>
              </div>

      </xpath>

    </template>
```

samebody help?

Answer (score 1):

change t-att-checked to t-attf-checked

an example:

t-attf-checked="#{user_name == 'Administrator' or False}"

Comment: it work, but I dont get value. cause I use the radio button if I click I get the value, If I click the radiobutton will get the value in backend. any solution?